# How to automate a set of apache spark commands?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

This is a common interview question I am facing and personally also thinking. Say for example I have written some lines of spark scala code to work on a banking data (eg, load, split, find top 10 investors, etc.).

Now, a question comes like do I need to run these commands everyday standalone? Or if there is a way to schedule them in batch or automate the run?

- how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need write your program (Scala, java ou python).

After, you can schedule it using your OS scheduler :

- `crontab` (on unix) (using .sh to call your program)
- `task scheduler` (on Windows) (using .bat to call your program)

*(nothing specific to spark here)*

Answer (score 0):

After writing your scala Spark code you can define an Akka Scheduler with the specific time after which you want your code to run. An example of Akka scheduler is :

```
val system : akka.actor.ActorSystem = _
system.scheduler.schedule(0 seconds, 10 minutes){
\\your scala code
}
```

Now your scala code will run after every 10 minutes.